# In Brazil, what would be the right way to write "Doctoral Thesis Proposal"?

Tags: phd, thesis, brazil

Though the location is Brazil, the language being used is English.  I do not want to write "Ph.D. Thesis" because there is no "Ph.D." degree in Brazil, that is, the degree name is not called "Ph.D.".  Over here one gets a doctoral degree (or however I should write it).

I see  "Master's Thesis" written everywhere, but I do not see "Doctorate's Thesis".  I see "Doctoral Thesis".  So it seems to me I cannot write "Doctorate's Thesis". I would appreciate some guidance, confirmation and hopefully a reference.  (For instance, perhaps there is a guide somewhere that offers rules for an international English-language usage.)  Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean there is no "PhD" degree in Brazil? "PhD Thesis" isn't a degree. PhD is, of course, just an abbreviation for "Doctor of Philosophy", where "philosophy" is interpreted very broadly.

Comment: Yes, I mean a "PhD" degree.  I corrected the question.  Thank you!  (As far as I know we should not translated such titles too freely because each country has its own requirements, implying degrees are more or less different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, I think it is hard to beat "Doctoral Thesis Proposal" for a suggestion to a supervisor about the research to be undertaken to achieve any doctorate (more or less equivalent to terminal degree). "Doctorate's degree" sounds foreign to the ear.

There are many sorts of doctorates, not just PhD (EdD, for example). But all involve "doctoral studies" and probably a "doctoral level thesis"

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_doctoral_degrees_in_the_US